# Valid information using ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm creating my own input fields based on `ControlValueAccessor`.

How to get validation info in such component?

Here is example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-valid?file=src/app/text-input.component.ts
Custom field is `required`.

In `TextInputComponent` I'm referring to `NgModel` but it is always `valid`.
`{{formGroup.get('text').valid}}` gives me correct value.

Answer (score 0):

When using ControlValueAccessor you must reframe which NgModel you should be looking at. By creating an input yourself, you must watch the validity of the custom input, and not the inner input.

What I mean by this, is that **app-text-input** should be seen, and used as you would the inner input. The NgModel on the inner input (is irrelevant), and is used just for the HTML templating of your new component.

Simply put, the reference of the input in your form is to the **app-text-input** component. And using the methods from the ControlValueAccessor interface you need to update and control the value, as the native input itself would.

For example:

```
<form ngForm="form">
  // the ngForm keeps the custom-inputs model

  // we put required here as this is now where we reference the model
  <custom-input [(ngModel)]="value" required>

    // this is just for templating, when you updating this value you must call the method writeValue, which sets the value of the custom-input which then validates the control.
    <input value="value" />

  </custom-input>

</form>
```

---

**Another solution**
You can also just pass the attributes down using @Input or @Attribute.

I've edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-valid-3vvnwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In this example you just pass the validation down:

**app.component.html**

```
<custom-input required=true>
</custom-input>
```

**custom-input.component.ts**

```
@Input() required: boolean;
```

**custom-input.component.html**

```
<input [required]="required" />
```

Comment: I understand but I need valid information to mark `input` tag with proper class. I found this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17736 and I see that there is not common solution - for ngModel and FormGroup

Comment: Yeah, then you will have to duplicate it on both Models, its complex but you can use the injector to get reference of the custom-input model and overwrite it with the inner inputs (this is super messy). The problem being, is by using ControlValueAccessor you are telling angular that you will control all the logic (of the custom component), to act as a 'real' input. It will do required validation for you. And will but the classes 'ng-dirty' on the custom tag. Then you can use styles to do stuff to the inner input, by checking the custom-input tag.

Comment: I've very quickly edited your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-valid-elbsbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html ... With this you can then use the classes on app-text-input to change the inner input.

Comment: @piernik I have also added, another solution (not as scalable), see the edited answer above.